# Java HashMap in Scala throws error

Tags: scala

The following Scala code that uses `java.util.HashMap` (I need to use Java because it's for a Java interface) works fine:

```
val row1 = new HashMap[String,String](Map("code" -> "B1", "name" -> "Store1"))
val row2 = new HashMap[String,String](Map("code" -> "B2", "name" -> "Store 2"))
val map1 = Array[Object](row1,row2)
```

Now, I'm trying to dynamically create `map1` :

```
val values: Seq[Seq[String]] = ....
val mapx = values.map {
      row => new HashMap[String,String](Map(row.map( col => "someName" -> col)))  <-- error
     }
val map1 = Array[Object](mapx)
```

But I get the following compilation error:

> type mismatch; found : Seq[(String, String)] required: (?, ?)

How to fix this?

Comment: are you sure `val row1 = new HashMap[String,String](Map("code" -> "B1", "name" -> "Store1"))` works?

Comment: yes, it's a JasperReports program that works fine

Comment: Passing a Scala immutable `Map` to `java.util.HashMap` does not seem correct. And post might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843445/how-to-populate-java-util-hashmap-on-the-fly-from-scala-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify your code a bit more:

```
val mapx = Map(Seq("someKey" -> "someValue"))
```

This still produces the same error message, so the error wasn't actually related to your use of Java `HashMap`s, but trying to use a `Seq` as an argument to Scala's `Map`.

The problem is that `Map` is variadic and expects key-value-pairs as its arguments, not some data structure containing them. In Java a variadic method can also be called with an array instead, without any type of conversion. This isn't true in Scala. In Scala you need to use `: _*` to explicitly convert a sequence to a list of arguments when calling a variadic method. So this works:

```
val mapx = Map(mySequence : _*)
```

Alternatively, you can just use `.to_map` to create a `Map` from a sequence of tuples:

```
val mapx = mySequence.toMap
```

Comment: how do you define `mySequence` ? What needs to be changed in the code posted in the question?

Comment: @ps0604 Doesn't matter. The point is that you can just call `toMap` on your sequence and you'll get a map.

Comment: Thanks, this works `val mapx = values.map { row => new HashMap[String,String](row.map( col => "someName" -> col).toMap) }`